# Angular 2/5 Missing SVG properties during build (but it runs!)

Tags: javascript, angular, svg

I am working with SVG path data. I have added two global JS files: [pathseg.js](https://github.com/progers/pathseg) (to polyfill `SVGPathElement.pathSegList`) and [normalizePath.js](https://gist.github.com/YannickBochatay/1297684) (to polyfill `SVGPathElement.normalizePath(...)`).

In `.angular-cli.json` I have added these two scripts:

```
"scripts": [
    "pathseg.js",
    "normalizePath.js"
],
```

In my program at runtime I inspect the SVG to learn its size and the size of its viewbox. This is the first compiler error: `SVGElement.width`, `SVGElement.height`, and  `SVGElement.viewbox` all give the error "Property '...' does not exist on type 'SVGElement'." So `ng build` and `ng serve` both fail.

Where it gets interesting is if I comment out all of this code, then `ng serve` can start serving. If I then uncomment the code, an error is reported, but the new code is served AND IT RUNS CORRECTLY. So I can't build it, but I can run it.

This same problem also occurs for the `normalizePath(...)` call. It works only if `ng serve` is already serving. `normalizePath.js` defines this function at runtime when it loads.

I must be missing something here. What could be the problem? Should I extend `SVGElement` to define its missing fields? And how do I let angular know that `normalizePath.js` defines `SVGPathElement.normalizePath(...)` at runtime? Can I use an annotation to tell the TS compiler to just build anyway?

```
@ViewChild( 'theSvg' ) svgRef: ElementRef;

excerpt( ) {
    let svg: SVGElement = this.svgRef.nativeElement;
    let minX: number = 0;
    let minY: number = 0;
    let width: number = svgElement.width.baseVal.value;
    let height: number = svgElement.height.baseVal.value;

    if ( svgElement.viewBox && svgElement.viewBox.baseVal.width > 0 ) {
        minX = svgElement.viewBox.baseVal.x;
        minY = svgElement.viewBox.baseVal.y;
        width = svgElement.viewBox.baseVal.width;
        height = svgElement.viewBox.baseVal.height;
    }

    let children: HTMLCollection = svgElement.children;
    for ( let i: number = 0; i < children.length; i++ ) {
        let child: Element = children.item( i );
        if ( child.tagName === 'path' ) {
            let pathData: SVGPathSegList = ( <SVGPathElement>child ).normalizePath( 2, 0.5 ).pathSegList;

            // ... do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There appears to be a syntax error on line 23 of normalizePath.js. That is at the end of the `var` declaration chain and should be terminated with a `;` but it is terminated with a `,`. This will not be overlooked by the transpolar/minifier etc. Try to fix that manually and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately still the same result.

Comment: The same error is repeated on line 165. You need to run these files through tslint!!

Comment: I added a `jsRules` section to `tslint.json` and duplicated the `rules` section (this should apply the same rules to both JavaScript and TypeScript I think?) When I lint the project with `ng lint`, it finds problems in my *.ts files but reports nothing for the *.js files. I think it's skipping those files. What is the correct way to lint the global JS files?

Comment: I'm not sure those commas are actually in error. For example, on line 23, it is followed by another variable definition, `getCurrentPoint`, which then ends the var list with a semicolon on line 44. The other case on line 165 is similar.

Comment: Looks like you're right. For jsHint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35605626/using-jshint-with-angular-ignore-angular-styles?s=2|87.9320